# Bootstrap submit button doesn't react

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, submit

I don't seem to get this code working in Chrome or IE. Whenever the 'Submit' button is clicked on, nothing seems to happen. The script.php file contains a script inserting the e-mail adress in an SQL database.

I've been searching in stackoverflow and the rest of the web for three hours now, without any result. I really hope you can help me out here

```
<!--e-mail form-->
<form role="form" method="POST" action="script.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail adress" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>   
    </div>                  
</form>
```

If you'd like to see it IRL: co-searching.be

Comment: Show us your script.php code. Also, is there any error inside php_error_log catched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with bootstrap. Your form submit behaviour is being intercepted via javascript in a script named `contact_me.js`.

What this script was supposed to accomplish, I don't know, but you might want to check that out. For instance, inn line 11 of this script you have

```
var name = $("input#name").val()
```

which is effectively reading the value of an input field that I don't see in your site. Consider not linking unnecessary scripts to your page.

Comment: I removed the connect_me.js file and it started working. thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in contact_me.js (jqBootstrapValidation). Look at console logs.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help me out! I'm new to this, how do I do that?

Comment: Do what? Check console? In Chrome: Ctrl + Shift + J. 
'Console' tab.